# How can I automatically restart, or close and then open, a specific application?

Tags: windows, script, cmd.exe

I've been playing a game that consistently crashes, but never during the first game. A workaround has been to completely close the game and then re-launch it, seemingly restarting the "game counter" back to 0.

Is it possible to write a simple script to automate this process? I'd imagine I need to kill the game + launcher processes, then open them after a short delay.

Comment: Yes, this is typically a very possible option. What have you tried? What research have you done? We're not a script writing service, so you'll need to start with research and attempts on your own, but once you've come up against something you're having trouble figuring out, we're here to help.

Comment: I appreciate where you're coming from, I just didn't know the right keywords to get started. After some stumbling around "batch scripts" seemed to be what I was looking for. Code posted below!

Comment: Nicely done. For not know what it was called you've figured it out rather quickly. Next thing you know you'll be an IT pro...

Comment: I actually remembered creating a batch file in high school (opened Notepad, wrote "name.bat" and saved as "name.bat"; open to watch the command line endlessly scroll and feel like a badass hacker), so it was more of tip of my tongue situation! Thanks for commenting, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Here's my code, saved into filename.bat.

```
@echo
cls
taskkill /IM [name].exe /T /F
taskkill /IM [name].exe /T /F
timeout /T 5
cd "[PATH]"
Start "" /b [name].exe
exit
```